# Google Analytics Experiments - Bypassing A/B Test

Tags: google-analytics, universal-analytics, google-experiments

I'm running an A/B test on a landing page using Google Analytics' Experiments feature (Universal Analytics).  Is it possible to bypass the experiment and always show the original version of the page, though a query string added to the URL or some other similar method?

I'm imagining it being something like `site.com/landing-page/?experiment=disabled`, but I haven't come across anything in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

If you append the `utm_expid` code generated to the experiment page you want to view, it will bypass the redirect.

For example: `www.example.com/index.html?utm_expid=121130413-11.qQUH2leXTuCxQsqdgxk9Rw.1` would always return the first page in the experiment.